# how can I provide files as inputs to `tsort`?

Tags: coreutils, tsort

The input to `tsort` can be provided as in this example:

```
$ tsort <<EOF
a b c
b c d e
EOF
```

If I have two files as inputs instead,

```
a
b
c
```

and

```
b
c
d
e
```

how can I provide the two files in bash as inputs to `tsort` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all entries of each file into a single line.

You can do so with an unquoted `$(...)` which will split on whitespace (and that includes newline) and then you can use `echo` on it to print the arguments into a single line.

This should work:

```
{ echo $(cat file1)
  echo $(cat file2)
} | tsort
```

This should produce the same output as your example does.

---

**UPDATE:** The input of tsort is broken on any whitespace, so preserving each file's contents in a single line isn't really important.

In that case, this should be enough:

```
cat file1 file2 | tsort
```

Though in your example, you don't really have a number of pairs, there is an odd number of items in your file1. As [you noticed already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482356/281844), that is a problem for tsort.