# tsort: -: input contains an odd number of tokens

Tags: sort, coreutils, tsort

coreutils manual says

> tsort reads its input as pairs of strings, separated by blanks,
>   indicating a partial ordering. The output is a total ordering that
>   corresponds to the given partial ordering. For example
>
> ```
> tsort <<EOF
> a b c
> d
> e f
> b c d e
> EOF
> ```
>
> will produce the output
>
> ```
> a
> b
> c
> d
> e
> f
> ```

What does "tsort reads its input as pairs of strings" mean, and what requirements does that put on the input?
In the example, does the first line `a b c` mean nothing itself, but `a` and `b` are paired, and so are `c` and `d`?

Why does this not work?

```
$ tsort <<EOF
> a b c
> b c d e
> EOF
tsort: -: input contains an odd number of tokens
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, tsort reads its inputs in pairs separated by any whitespace, including newlines.

So the example from the tsort documentation:

```
tsort <<EOF
a b c
d
e f
b c d e
EOF
```

Defines the following pairs of orderings:

- a < b
- c < d
- e < f
- b < c
- d < e

And putting these all together, you get to a ordering of a < b < c < d < e < f, which in this case is a total ordering.

A reading of the source code confirms that, tsort uses [readtoken() from gnulib](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/16aa5a2efe82e01a147b4022258fa9a272f67625/lib/readtokens.c#L66) with a set of delimiters comprised by [space, tab and newline](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v8.30/src/tsort.c#L48), in other words, any whitespace.

(My initial interpretation of that tsort example, to answer [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482277/281844), was that a line with `b c d e` created three implicit pairs, b < c, c < d and d < e, but that's really not the case, all whitespace is interpreted the same, including newlines, and a single pair is read at a time.)

Answer (score 8):

`tsort` does a topological sorting of a directed graph.  It gets the graph as pairs of nodes. These constitute a partial ordering of the graph and `tsort` gives you a total ordering as the result (there may be more than one total ordering of the graph though, see [the documentation for the `-f` and `-h` options on BSD systems](https://man.openbsd.org/tsort) (not available on GNU systems AFAIK)).

Example of a real graph (these are the OpenBSD packages required to build the `shells/bash` package on an OpenBSD system):

```
$ make -C /usr/ports/shells/bash build-dir-depends
shells/bash devel/ccache
shells/bash devel/gettext
devel/gettext devel/ccache
devel/gettext archivers/xz
archivers/xz devel/ccache
devel/gettext converters/libiconv
converters/libiconv devel/ccache
devel/gettext converters/libiconv
```

A pair, `A B`, in this list means "`A` is connected to `B`" (in that order, since it's a directed graph), and in the particular case shown here it means "`A` depends on `B`" (`converters/libiconv` needs to be built before `devel/gettext` because the latter depends on the former).

`tsort` takes the the partial ordering of pairs of nodes and returns a list of nodes in a total ordering compatible with that partial ordering:

```
$ make -C /usr/ports/shells/bash build-dir-depends | tsort -r
devel/ccache
archivers/xz
converters/libiconv
devel/gettext
shells/bash
```

Here, I've instructed `tsort` to reverse the resulting ordering (not possible on GNU systems as `-r` is not an option to GNU `tsort`), which gives me the order in which the system needs to build the packages while at the same time honouring the dependencies between them (ending up with building the final `shells/bash` package).

If `tsort` gets an input line

```
a b c d
```

then this is the same as

```
a b
c d
```

and as

```
a b c
d
```

That is, it always reads the nodes of the graph in *pairs*, no matter whether these are separated by spaces or newlines.  The issue with your data,

```
a b c
b c d e
```

is that it can't be read as a list of pairs as it contains an odd number of nodes.